# Concatenate lists of strings item-wise in Python

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

This is a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question for golfing in [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Suppose you have two lists of strings, and you want to concatenate the corresponding entries from each list. E.g. with `a=list("abcd")` and `b=list("1234")`, calculate `["a1","b2","c3","d4"]`.

This is trivial in array-based programming languages, where operations generally apply memberwise to lists. For example, in my golfing language [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), the code is simply `a.b`. But in Python, it's not so easy.

The Pythonic way is probably to use `zip` and a list comprehension (25 chars):

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Another method is `map` with a lambda function (23):

```
map(lambda x,y:x+y,a,b)
```

The following is the shortest I've come up with (21):

```
map("".join,zip(a,b))
```

Is there any shorter method?

Assume that the lists are the same length and that some kind of iterable is all that's needed (so a `map` object is fine in Python 3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for golfing in Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python)

Comment: @Mast Does the tips list contain an answer which addresses this specific question?

Comment: @MartinBüttner If it isn't, it should. Prevents cluttering and keeps all the tricks togeter, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 20 chars

```
map(str.__add__,a,b)
```

Uses the build-in method string addition method `__add__` that is invoked by `+` on strings in place of your anonymous function `lambda x,y:x+y`.

Comment: You know, I thought of `str.__add__` but for some reason didn't check to see if it was shorter.

Comment: @DLosc the real advantage of this answer is using `map` with multiple iterables, which dis the zipping automatically. Without that it wouldn't be shorter. Note that if in your code you have to access some of the `__*__` methods it may be shorter to do `from operator import *` and then use `map(add,a,b)`.